# How can get a specific widget in a tab of Notebook?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have a problem with the manipulation of widgets in a tab of notebook. I create a custom class which inherits from notebook widget. As below code;

'
class CustomNB(ttk.Notebook):
    def **init**(self, topWindow):
        super().**init**()
        self["width"] = 505
        self["height"] = 200
        self.enable_traversal()
        self.bind("<>", self.selected_tab)

```
    self.addButtonList = list()

    self.v = StringVar()
    for i in range(3):
        self.cur_tab = "tab" + str(i)
        self.cur_tab = Frame(self)
        self.cur_tab_name = "Group " + chr(65 + i)
        self.add(self.cur_tab, text=self.cur_tab_name, sticky="e", compound="text")

        self.curGroup = Entry(self.cur_tab, width=5, justify="center", textvariable=self.v)
        self.curGroup.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NESW")
        # self.curGroup.bind("<Return>", self.chName)

        self.addButton = ttk.Button(self.cur_tab, text="Add File")
        self.addButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NESW ")
        # self.addButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.addFile)

        self.addButtonList.append(id(self.addButton))
        self.removeButton = ttk.Button(self.cur_tab, text="Remove File")
        self.removeButton.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="NESW ")
        # self.removeButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.removeFile)

        self.cl = Label(self.cur_tab, width=5, height=1)
        self.cl.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="NESW ")

        self.colorButton = ttk.Button(self.cur_tab, text="Choose Color")
        self.colorButton.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="NESW")
        # self.colorButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.groupColor)

        self.selList = Listbox(self.cur_tab, width=70, height=12, bg="#ADADAD",
                               selectmode=EXTENDED)
        self.selList.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=5)
        self.curGroup.insert(0, self.cur_tab_name)
```

'

How can I get and manipulate tabs content individually? Like, I want to change specifically text of the seventh tab label and find out addButton id in a specific tab.

Bests

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Notebook.tab(tab_id, option=None, **kw)
```

tab_id can be your target tab's index as a integer.

This function has a few applications:

If `option` is defined, it returns the value of that option.

If you want to change an option, eg. text, simply write `Notebook.tab(tab_id, text = "newtext")`

If you leave it at `Notebook.tab(tab_id)`, it returns a dictionary of all of the options values.

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Tkans for reply. My problem is to get specific object in a tab. In the script every tab has 1 label, 3 buttons, and I create 10 tabs. I want to change name of the label widget in tab 4

Comment: This would be difficult with the current code as `self.cl` is overwritten each time. I have had similar problems in the past and found that the easiest way was to assign tabs to a list index rather than a variable. As far as I know, there is no way to return the object using a `Notebook()` function. Sorry that I can't be of any more help.

Comment: Dragon, you are rigth. Yesterday, I realized to use List and at a certain level I got almost what I want.